# Default value set in attributes form in QGIS is not working in QField

Tags: qgis, qfield

I Have set a default value in attributes form of a vector file that works fine in the QGIS desktop.

[image: Attributes form]

[image]

But when I transfer the project in QField the default value setting doesn't work.

[image]

Is there is a way to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It apperas you are using a custom function `dms()`? The extract of the expression shown in your screenshots does not correspond to the parameters expected for the [`to_dms()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#to-dms) function, which should specify the axis and decimal values.

I don't think custom functions are currently supported in QField as I don't think the app supports startup macros (which are currently how you save custom function definitions in projects for desktop QGIS, AFAIK).

If you adapt your expression to use the standard `to_dms()` function, it seems to work (tested on QGIS 3.28.15 and 3.34.3, QField version 3.1.9)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note also your lat/lon order as shown is incorrect; Y (=latitude) should come before X (=longitude).